# Is necessary to specify a length of Integer when create a table in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite, integer, create-table, variable-length

I understand that if you know the length of the value you'll receive you must specify the length. e.g. you will receive a text string with length of 20 always, you specify it when you create your table

**My question is:** i'll receive integers but lengths may vary between 5 and 10, do i have to put "mycolumnint INTEGER (10)" -understanding that you are prepare to receive the max length value- or leave it just as "mycolumnint INTEGER"?

Comment: What do you mean by lenght? The number of digits?

Comment: SQLite is very lax about data types. Length limits on numbers and strings are ignored (they're only parsed for compatibility with other databases) and you can generally insert any data type into any column you want.

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes, the number of digits. E.g. myint INTEGER (5) = 00001 or 22222 or 99999

Comment: This is nothing you have to care about when using SQLite. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

It is enough to just define a column as having the type `INTEGER`. SQLite will take care of the rest.

Comment: Column types are not the same as internal data types; is not even necessary to declare the column type.